# Spectrum of doubly stochastic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices

> Let $M$ be a doubly stochastic matrix in which every entry is strictly positive. Prove that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have $\lambda \neq 1 \implies |\lambda|< 1$ and the geometric and algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ are the same.

I'm sure this is trivial, but I can't see it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
try to define an appropriate norm on the matrix so that it is 1 for every doubly stochastic matrix and use the usual equation Av=pv.Now apply norm on this eqn and derive the fact that |p|<1 or  you can use the spectral radius formula to directly get the result.1 is the largest eigenvalue so by perron-frobenius theorem,every other eigenvalue has absolute value strictly less  than 1

Comment: Got it, thanks. Does that also imply in someway that the multiplicities of $1$ are the same?

Oops. Actually I didn't get it. I can only show that $|p| \leq 1$. Can't prove it's strictly smaller than 1.

Comment: $\lambda=-1$ is a possibility.

Comment: In order to use the Perron-Frobenius theorem I need $M$ to be irreducible which doesn't necessarily happen, I believe.

Comment: perron frobenius holds for positive matrices.. check wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

Comment: Ok, but why can't $\lambda$ be $-1$ or any root of $1$ for that matter?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Follows from P-F too. I was looking at a different version of the theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of the following two facts:

1. The Perron-Frobenius theorem for positive matrices.
2. If $A\ge 0$ (entrywise), then $A$ has row-sums equal to one if and only if $Ae = e$, in which $e$ denotes the all-ones vector, i.e., the spectral radius of $A$ is one.